# Bind Join in database

Tags: database, join

What is a bind join in the context of database, from what I read:

> A Bind Join is a nested loop join where intermediate results from the
>   outer relation are passed to the inner to be used as filter

But what does it means concretely

Answer (score 0):

In index join, tuples having a particular attribute are fetched and only those that join with a tuple are joined. In a nested loop join, imagine having n loops. The intermediate result of the join of the k outer loops could be used to filter out the tuples from the next join.

Another citation in the paper Agora, efficient implementation of bind joins minimizes data transfers if the size of the attribute(s) to be passed across the join is important.

Comment: Do you have a reference or more information for "Agora"?

Comment: http://db.ucsd.edu/CSE291-SP03/manolescu00agora.pdf . Sorry for the late response.